# insert column that contains total counts grouped by values in one column

Tags: t-sql

I have a table `departments` that contains the name of a employees and the department they work in. I would like to add a column that contains the number of employees per department.

| Name | Department | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Doe | Clothing | 2 |
| John Doe | Clothing | 2 |
| Jane Doe | IT | 1 |

There are two employees in the Clothing department and 1 in the IT department.

I know I can get the info like so in t-sql:

```
SELECT Department, count(*) AS Count FROM departments GROUP BY Department
```

What I'm unable to figure out is how to add this info to each row in the table `departments`.

Comment: use a `VIEW`, don't add a column to the table for information like this. You can use `count(*) over (partition by Department) as TheCountYouWant` in your `SELECT` query

Comment: thanks. i'm just presenting a toy example here. there is a reason i would like to add this as a column.

Comment: You can simply alter the table to add the column. `ALTER TABLE departments ADD theCount INT`. After that use a update query to update theCount

Comment: the problem is that `Count` will only have 2 rows above (one for each `Department`), but the table has 3 (one for each `Name`).

Comment: Don't quite understand your last comment. Anyway this will gives you the result that you want `SELECT Name, Department, count(*) over (partition by Department) AS Count FROM departments `

Comment: Thanks. I may have not emphasized enough where I am stuck. I am able to get the result, with the select statement that I provided, as well as the one you kindly provided. The issue is that either one gives me the count for each department. What I need to figure out is how to add the right count to each row in the original table, depending on the value in the column `Department`. The table is not necessarily sorted by department. For example, the `Count` for `Clothing` is two. Now I need to add a two to each row where department is `Clothing`. Does it require a `JOIN` operation?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your issue here. Does this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ecadced8cdb3e3143e27c462415c4a7) works for you ?

Comment: Thanks again. Using your select statement does indeed produce the results I needed, unlike the select statement I show above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP answered their question from the comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @squirrel, the following code works:

```
update d set [Count] = theCount
from
(
    select *, count(*) over (partition by Department) as TheCount
    from   departments
) d
```